# Why doesn't the Web3.py transact function work?

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3py

I am trying to follow an online tutorial, but I am getting errors all the time. Can someone please help me? I cannot find any answer that could by handy.

Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Greeter {
    string public greeting;
    
    constructor() public {
        greeting = 'Hello';
    }
    
    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
    
    function getGreeting() view public returns(string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Python code:

```
  from web3 import Web3
    import json
    
    abi = '[{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"greet","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"greeting","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"_greeting","type":"string"}],"name":"setGreeting","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'
# bytecode 'object'
bytecode = '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'

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'))
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
greeter_contract = web3.eth.contract(
    abi=json.loads(abi),
    bytecode=bytecode,
)
tx_hash = greeter_contract.constructor().transact()
```

Returns:

```
    raise ContractLogicError(f'execution reverted: {response["error"]["message"]}')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

I do not know what may be causing that many errors.

Comment: I think your `bytecode` needs an `0x` up front.

Comment: @SimonR thank you for the help. That's right 0x in front was causing the problem, but after it once worked, it started to work even without that 0x. Can you maybe explain it, I am new to the ethereum programming and I kinda do not understand it.